# Maintaining Postgres copies of fdw tables from Oracle

Tags: postgresql, mirroring, oracle-fdw

I have a production Oracle 11g server, from which I want to copy data regularly to PostgreSQL 10.14 database for DWH uses, so as not to overload the production with analytics queries.

I have succesfully mirrored the neccessary Oracle views with FDW wrapper, so relevant Oracle structures are accessible, and I have a couple of functions and queries I run regularly, to copy oracle_fdw view data to Postgres tables.

As Oracle is used for a business system, which is maintained by external support company, they are occasionally tweaking some of the views I copy, in order to enable new functionality in the business system. For example, they are adding columns to Oracle tables and views, and/or extending some column sizes.

When that happens, the Oracle fdw views in Postgres need to be reimported, or else they fail when trying to fetch a column, in which place there is another column now, or the column sizes don't match anymore, or there are more columns in the actual Oracle structs than in the fdw imported view.

Reimport, however, still breaks the queries and/or functions which use constructs like:

`INSERT INTO my_pg_mirror_table_archive SELECT * FROM oracle_fdw_view;`

because as most of Oracle structures I copy, are actually views, the new Oracle columns can and do sometimes appear in middle of others, instead of at end, like:

`oracle_fdw_table`: col1 **new_col3** col2

which means even if I add column to my_pg_mirror_table_archive the above query will fail, as it will expect the column order col1 col2 new_col3.

I can circumvent that by manually specifying column order instead of SELECT * , however, the more tables the more possibility of mistakes and manual work.

In addition there are views on the pg_mirror_table_archive, which depend on it and need to be recreated after every such column addition/change.

Are there any tools or best practices that can automagically or semi-automatically maintain such relationship(s) and do the behind scenes work, so that my postgres tables always match the oracle ones?

Comment: I don't think there is a way to do that.

Answer (score 1):

> I have a production Oracle 11g server, from which I want to copy data regularly to PostgreSQL 10.14 database for DWH uses ...

Why move the data from Oracle to Postgres at all?

Why not use a Data Guard based solution to populate your Data Warehouse?

Three possibilities:

**Logical Standby**:

Data Guard applies *SQL* on the Standby (instead of the more efficient, Redo vectors).
Logical Standbys can be used to load-balance near real-time, read-only activity away from the Primary.
The Logical Standby database can be structurally different (i.e. different indexes, etc.) from the Primary ...   and therein lies your problem if the vendor goes and *changes* stuff - this *will not* get carried through into the Logical Standby automatically.  You would have to find out the changes and re-make them in the Standby.
Alternatively, you could *rebuild* the Logical Standby database after each Product release or build a *new* Logical Standby, route Users to that one and throw the old one away).

***Active* Data Guard**:

This is a "cost option", but it might be your *simplest* solution.

Using *Active* Data Guard, your Physical Standby database becomes *readable* and is [*very*] near real-time up-to-date with the Primary.

The Standby database is structurally identical to the Primary.

**Snapshot Standby**:

Spends *some* of its life as an inaccessible, Physical Standby database (unless you *pay* for *Active* Data Guard), but when you want to use it, you "unplug" it from the Data Guard configuration and *open* it as a database in its own right, with Data as of when it was "unplugged".  Each night, you "plug" it back into the Data Guard configuration and redo (held on the Standby's host) is re-applied, bringing the database back "up-to-date" with the Primary.
The Standby database is structurally identical to the Primary *unless* you choose to add extra indexes, etc., after the "unplugging" activity.

> Reimport ... still breaks ... constructs like:
>
> INSERT INTO my_pg_mirror_table_archive SELECT * FROM oracle_fdw_view;

And this is just *one* of the reasons why should you *never* use "select *" in Production Code.

Comment: "*Why not use a Data Guard based solution to populate your Data Warehouse*" - license cost? Or maybe it's a first step to migrate away from Oracle completely?

Comment: Active Data Guard sounds like a potential option, however, there are a number of hurdles that make using Oracle for the backup/standby solution unlikely. Among them the costs, the fact that the original Oracle db is not under our control, and some others issues due to which we are actually using Postgres in the first place.